# How to configure Hessian on Spring MVC with xml config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hessian

I am using Hessian in a Spring MVC project. I create server side implementation and then would like to configure the client. Client can be configured with code that uses `HessianProxyFactory` for the initialization of the client. The URL that is used is now hard coded in the code, but I would like to wire the service some how as a Spring bean so that the code side config would be handled with `@Autowired` annotation.

How to make this? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is described in [20.3.3 Linking in the service on the client](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-caucho-protocols-hessian-client):

```
<bean id="accountService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://remotehost:8080/remoting/AccountService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.AccountService"/>
</bean>
```

Where `example.AccountService` is the service interface that the server implements. The client also needs that interface, but you probably know that.

Alternatively use Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public HessianProxyFactoryBean accountService() {
    HessianProxyFactoryBean factory = new HessianProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceUrl("http://remotehost:8080/remoting/AccountService");
    factory.setServiceInterface(AccountService.class);
    return factory;
}
```

Now you are capable of simply injecting:

```
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;
```

The [`HessianProxyFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/caucho/HessianProxyFactoryBean.html) allows you to configure various other features like security and timeouts.